Error message in parameter tuning: OptimInstanceMultiCrit is deprecated. Use OptimInstanceBatchMultiCrit instead
I have an error message when I run a tuning process using the function mlr3tuning::ti from the mlr3 package:
Here is a reproducible example:
task <- tsk("sonar")
tuner <- mlr3tuning::tnr("mbo")
instance <- mlr3tuning::ti(task = task,
                           learner = mlr3tuningspaces::lts(mlr3::lrn("classif.rpart", predict_type = "prob")),
                           resampling = mlr3::rsmp("cv", folds = 5) ,
                           measures = mlr3::msrs(c("classif.auc", "classif.ce")),
                           terminator = mlr3tuning::trm("evals", n_evals = 20))

OptimInstanceMultiCrit is deprecated. Use OptimInstanceBatchMultiCrit instead.

tuner$optimize(instance)

Error in private$.optimizer$optimize(inst) : 
  attempt to apply non-function

Here are the versions of packages:

When I load the packages only from CRAN, I get this error message:
Loading required package: mlr3tuning
Loading required package: paradox
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘mlr3tuning’ in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]):
 namespace ‘mlr3misc’ 0.15.0 is already loaded, but >= 0.15.0.9000 is required
Error: package ‘mlr3tuning’ could not be loaded

Is it no longer possible to use the ti() function?

I think you should report this on mlr3 github - seems like a partially implemented update.

Can you post a complete example that allows to reproduce the problem please?

Your example works fine for me without any problems.

@LarsKotthoff On the side, it doesn't work. Could it be a version issue as suggested by
missuse? I've included my versions in mon post.

Might be an issue with the unreleased github versions then. Works for me with CRAN versions (both for mlr3tuning and mlr3tuningspaces).

What version of  {paradox} do you have installed? you could try installing {paradox} from CRAN rather than GitHub, downgrading to 0.11.1 helped me.

@HughGraham. Thank you for your comment. I have version 1.0.0 of {paradox}. I downloaded version 0.11.1 from CRAN, but I still have this error message. Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘mlr3tuning’ in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]):  namespace ‘mlr3misc’ 0.15.0 is already loaded, but >= 0.15.0.9000 is required Error: package ‘mlr3tuning’ could not be loaded

Okay try also installing mlr3misc and then mlr3tuning from CRAN. I had to lock this down in an renv DESCRIPTION file. I can share that tomorrow if the manual install still doesn't work...

@HughGraham Great! The issue has been resolved. The problem arose from the versions of the packages paradox and bbotk. I didn't have the versions from CRAN. A huge thank you for your help!

Ah yes I forgot about bbotk! Glad it's sorted, I suspect it'll all be sorted in a few days once the rest of the ecosystem catches up, looks like there is quite a lot of refactoring going on right now!
